# Postgres: Calculate the time interval (in seconds) between successive values

Tags: python, database, postgresql, datetime

I was wondering how we can compute the difference of successive date-times (for example in days or seconds), considering the sample table below:

```
time                       value
2020-03-30 00:25:10       10112
2020-04-02 08:04:03       45665
2020-04-10 09:55:56       112
2020-04-10 13:12:00       858
2020-04-28 10:15:59       89965
2020-05-30 22:31:02       12
```

Here is a desired result generated by [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas)' `diff()`:

```
0                NaT
1    3 days 07:38:53
2    8 days 01:51:53
3    0 days 03:16:04
4   17 days 21:03:59
5   32 days 12:15:03
```

In other words, what is the Postgres equivalent to pandas' `diff()`?

Comment: The `lag()` window function will do that nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply subtract a lagged timestamp, and then output as an interval or in the format you desire using [`to_char`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-formatting.html). For example:

```sql
SELECT "time" - LAG("time") OVER (ORDER BY "time") AS diff,
       TO_CHAR("time" - LAG("time") OVER (ORDER BY "time"), 'DD "days" HH24:MI:SS') AS cdiff
FROM data
```

Output:

```
diff                                            cdiff
null                                            null
{"days":3,"hours":7,"minutes":38,"seconds":53}  03 days 07:38:53
{"days":8,"hours":1,"minutes":51,"seconds":53}  08 days 01:51:53
{"hours":3,"minutes":16,"seconds":4}            00 days 03:16:04
{"days":17,"hours":21,"minutes":3,"seconds":59} 17 days 21:03:59
{"days":32,"hours":12,"minutes":15,"seconds":3} 32 days 12:15:03
```

[Demo on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aDsceDoU941br5DLySWpDS/1)

**Note** if you want a row number as well, you can add one as

```sql
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY "time") - 1 AS rownum
```

You can also get the value in seconds using [`EXTRACT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-datetime.html):

```sql
EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM "time" - LAG("time") OVER (ORDER BY "time")) AS seconds
```

Output

```
rownum  diff                                            cdiff               seconds
0       null                                            null                null
1       {"days":3,"hours":7,"minutes":38,"seconds":53}  03 days 07:38:53    286733
2       {"days":8,"hours":1,"minutes":51,"seconds":53}  08 days 01:51:53    697913
3       {"hours":3,"minutes":16,"seconds":4}            00 days 03:16:04    11764
4       {"days":17,"hours":21,"minutes":3,"seconds":59} 17 days 21:03:59    1544639
5       {"days":32,"hours":12,"minutes":15,"seconds":3} 32 days 12:15:03    2808903
```

[Demo on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aDsceDoU941br5DLySWpDS/3)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And how we can generate results in the number of seconds? For example, instead of `00:01:10` it outputs `70 seconds`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT row_number() OVER w - 1,
       time - lag(time) OVER w
FROM tab
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY time)
ORDER BY time;
```

`row_number` counts the result rows, and `lag` gets you the value from the previous row in the defined order.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And if we want these intervals in seconds, what can we do?